# Firebase push notification alert sound is not playing in background mode in iOS 10

Tags: ios, firebase, background, push-notification, ios10

I am implementing Apple push notification in my native iOS app.
Push notification is implemented via FireBase.
It's working perfect in iOS 9 & earlier.

I am facing one issue in iOS 10. Push notification is working fine for in iOS 10 with other state but **When app is in background, sound of my push notification is not playing.**
For other state of app , it's all ok.
Only issue with background mode.

Below is my code for Implement push notification.

Insdie

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Below is Registration code:

```
////////// FireBase////////////
    // Register for remote notifications
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            center.delegate = self;
            [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
                if( !error ){
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                }
            }];

            [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }


    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
```

Below are the delegate(s) for manage received notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    [self manageAppAfterReceiveNotific: userInfo];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{

    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    [self manageAppAfterReceiveNotific: userInfo];
}
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {

    NSLog(@"%@", [remoteMessage appData]);

    [self manageAppAfterReceiveNotific: [remoteMessage appData]];
}
#endif
```

Below is my PayLoad :

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "any text";
            title = "New Notification";
        };
        badge = 1;
        "content-available" = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
    extra = "{\"childrenId\":\"48\",\"timestamp\":\"1479724388\"}";
    "gcm.message_id" = "Message ID";
    noteType = "CHECK_OUT";
}
```

Comment: can you show the payload of your notification ?

Comment: @balkaran singh, I will update my question & Add PayLoad inside it.

Comment: Hi, Uploade payload,

Answer (score 0):

According to firebase document, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref, you should put "sound" filed into notification message, please refer Table 2a